# Question about Logistic Regression - 2

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, statistical-inference, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

How should I tell the difference between those two formulas in the circles below.
I am studying logistic regression and I have faced two different formulas from two different documents. I don't know if those two formulas are saying the same or slightly talking about different things. My guess is that the formula. 1 is only for one variable, but the formula. 2 is for many variables. Maybe it looks like a simple algebra, but I just want to make sure on this.

Please let me have your expertise about this. 
I am sorry if I have tagged the wrong places.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The second formula is the product $Y_1\cdots Y_N$ of the variables $Y_i$ in the first formula. Also note that $\binom{n}{y}=\frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}$.

Comment: Thank you and allow me to ask you one more thing that I wonder in my head.

Does $y_i$ mean discrete numbers such as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Usually, upper case letters stand for _variables_ and lower case letters for their _realizations_. So, $P[Y=y]$ means the probability that the RV $Y$ takes on the number $y$.

Comment: @user122358 The second formula seems to be the Maximum-Likelihood estimator for the expectation of the binomial Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In the first formula one reads the prob. distribution of a binomial random variable $Y_i$, with $Y_i \sim B(n_i,\pi_i)$.

For the second formula, I believe some interpretation is needed. As in the l.h.s. of second formula  some $\beta$'s and an integer $N$ appear, I will consider  a regression context with a maximum likelihood estimation.

Then, let $\{x_i, y_i\}_{i=1,\dots,N}$ be collected data with the realizations $y_i\in 1,\dots,n_i$ sampled from binomial random variables $Y_i$ as above, for all $i=1,\dots, N$.

One believes that the $x_i$'s have some explanatory power over the $y_i$'s. For this reason one tries to estimate some parameters $\beta$'s that maximize the conditional likelihood of the $Y_i$'s given the data $x_i$'s. To do so one introduces the (sample)  likelihood

$$L(\beta):=\sum_{i=1}^N P(Y_i = y_i | x_i, \beta):= \sum_{i=1}^N f(\bf X_i, \beta), $$
where $\mathbf{X}_i=(x_i,y_i) $ is the $i$-th datum and, by definition,

$$f(\mathbf{X}_i, \beta)=P(Y_i = y_i | x_i, \beta)= \frac{n_i!}{y_i!(n_i-y_i)!}\pi_i(x_i,\beta)^{y_i}(1-\pi_i(x_i,\beta))^{1-y_i}. $$

In other words, the probability of success $\pi_i$ of the $i$-th binomial variable $Y_i$ is now a function of the $i$-th datum $x_i$ **and** the parameters $\beta$'s. As this parametrization is in general non linear, the maximum likelihood estimation of the $\beta$'s is performed iteratively through numerical algorithms (Newton-Raphson).